# body tag does't take all window width +1600px

Tags: html, css

i have a div which should be just half displayed (design purpose) ,the div is work fine for screen < 1200 px, but when i come to large screens i got my div totally displayed and that because the body dosen't cover all the screen

i tried to make max-width and width:100% to the body and without success i had the same problem

this is the div style

```
.testimonials .right-effect{
   border-radius: 81px;
   background-color: #0be881;
   width: 227px;
   height: 152px;
   transform: rotate(-56deg);
   right: -120px;
   bottom: 0;
 }
```

and the body style

```
body{margin:0}
```

this is a picture to the problem with the blue section is the body and the green is my div

[image: Problem]
<sub>(source: [gulfupload.com](https://s1.gulfupload.com/i/00072/jln12qkimlcu.png))</sub>

Comment: What's with the style attribute in the html element? Are you sure that doesn't confuse the browser?

Comment: html had no styles,yes i tried in both chrome and firefox

Comment: Can you add a fiddle or codepen to reproduce it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank u ,
i found the solution , it's just that i need to  hide the overflow from the body element

```
body{margin:0;overflow-x:hidden;}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Use the CSS3 Viewport-percentage feature.](https://www.w3schools.com/csSref/css_units.asp) (vw) and [Calc](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/func_calc.asp)

This way you can do sth like `left: calc(50% - 120px + 50vw);`

`50% - 120px` will center your element (I assume `120px` is half width of element);

`+ 50vw` will move element to the right ( `- 50vw` will move to the left);

Don't forget that your element must be `position: absolute` or `position: relative;` (relative to body or any other centered element) for this to work.